# Dropping index column of mutiple excel files in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have multiple excel sheets that have identical column names. When I was saving the files from previous computations I forgot to set ‘Date’ as index and now all of them (40) have index columns with numbers from 1-200. If I load these into python they get an additional index column again resulting in 2 unnamed columns. I know I can use the glob function to access all my files. But is there a way I can access all the files, drop/delete the unnamed index column and set the new index to the date column

Here is an example of 1 excel sheet  right now

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'': [0, 1,2,3,4],
'Date': [1930, 1931, 1932, 1933,1934],
'value': [11558522, 12323552, 13770958, 18412280, 13770958],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think simpliest is set wrong first column to index and then use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for rewrite them by `Date` column:

```
import glob, os

for file in glob.glob('subset/*.xlsx'):

    df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=[0]).set_index('Date')
    print (df)

    #new excel files

    h,t = os.path.split(file)
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(h, 'new_' + t))

    #overwrite excel files (first backup data if something failed for avoid lost data)
    #df.to_excel(file)
```

Comment: this worked perfect. but how do i know save the dataframe (df) as individual excel files

Comment: `df.to_excel('new_' + file)` throws a file not found error. if i try the overwrite it does not overwrite the previous files

Comment: @Tamarie - To same folder like original data, only changed filenames

Comment: oh yes i see it. put it only saved 1 file (the last one) not all the files

Comment: so i have new_file1 in my folder but it neglected saving files 2 - 20

Comment: it finally worked. turns out i wasnt doing this in my for loop. i had split the code thats why it was doing it for 1 file only. Thank you so much for the help. The solution works perfect now

Comment: @Tamarie - Yop, I test it and working for me perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208920/discussion-between-tamarie-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

dfs = [pd.read_csv(file).set_index('Date')[['value']] for file in glob.glob("/your/path/to/folder/*.csv")]

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do that with pandas is:

```py
>>> df = df.drop('', axis=1)
>>> df = df.set_index('Date')
>>> df
         value
Date          
1930  11558522
1931  12323552
1932  13770958
1933  18412280
1934  13770958
```

(I did the above from memory, but a general tip for these kinds of things is to look in the documentation for appropriate functions. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html )

You can also specify header column when loading the files:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

> index_colint, list of int, default None
>
> Column (0-indexed) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. Pass None if
> there is no such column. If a list is passed, those columns will be combined
> into a MultiIndex. If a subset of data is selected with usecols, index_col is
> based on the subset.